# How to print the matrix part of a file

Tags: awk, python

I have a file that has strings and float numbers. I want to load this file and then print the matrix part of the file to can access to the matrix elements.

file.text

```
laimfnllvbms
ksdvkdv=ksmgfgmf
kfdjdj=4o53024

0 10 

   C        -5.079679       -0.614855        0.628813
   O        -5.090496       -1.535841       -0.185383
   N         -4.068243       -0.015776        1.175251
   H        -4.152798        0.774414        1.777298
   C        -2.706356       -0.272545        0.750101
   H        -2.712997       -0.826000       -0.177284
   C        -2.003241        1.167450        0.660391
   H       -1.795397        1.550152        1.682476
   H       -2.809862        1.800846        0.233202
   C        -0.756939        1.208105       -0.169144
```

output

```
            -5.079679       -0.614855        0.628813
            -5.090496       -1.535841       -0.185383
             -4.068243       -0.015776        1.175251
            -4.152798        0.774414        1.777298
            -2.706356       -0.272545        0.750101
            -2.712997       -0.826000       -0.177284
            -2.003241        1.167450        0.660391
           -1.795397        1.550152        1.682476
           -2.809862        1.800846        0.233202
            -0.756939        1.208105       -0.16914
```

matrix element [1,1] = -5.079679

matrix element [5,1] = -2.706356

Comment: Would you be willing to post a sample of your desired output?

Comment: Did you want to end up with the matrix data in a variable that could access like $element[5,1]?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is always the way you provided above.

```
awk 'NF == 4 {$1="";print}' matrix.txt
```

This prints all lines with 4 columns of data and blanks out the first column.

Answer (score 0):

To add more checking to the syntax, you can try something like the following. This will work only if the second field has always a negative value.

```
awk -vOFS="\t" 'NF==4 && $2 ~ "^-[0-9]" {$1="";printf("%s\n", $0)}' matrix.txt
```

- -vOFS (Use TAB as Output Field Seperator)
- If # of fields is 4 and the second field matches the regex.. then blank the first field and print the rest of the fields.
- In case you have numbers like

  `C        14.756939        1.208105       -0.169144`

then you can use `$2 ~ "^-?[0-9]"` wich will check for positive values too.